# Select list is clicking but blue tick not displaying

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

i have add android platform 8.0.0 but after adding api level 28 some UI Problem in android

1)select list is clicking but blue tick not displaying but after click ok button then displaying blue tick
2)button click but fire action after click other button

Comment: add code and picture, explain more in these question

Comment: hi! please provide some code or images to understand better

Comment: please check video
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AHCg41DoY3AqD5b75MF5RtJT1KqZX210